# How use different render of slide in react slick

Tags: reactjs, display, react-slick

How use different render of slide in react slick. I have a slider with 10 slide and i display with 3 slidesShows with center mode and I want to add delete button on slide in center but not other , in every slide when slide is in the center but don't know how. Who can help me ?